# OmniAuth bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, omniauth

I'm trying to use omniauth with a new project. I'm using it on other projects on my computer with no issues. 'gem list' confirms:

```
rails 3.2.9 
omniauth 1.1.4
```

Everything is fine until I bundle install, at which point I get this error message:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'ominiauth (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails'
gem 'ominiauth'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `omniauth` as `ominiauth`.

Comment: rookie mistake if I've ever made one. That's what I get for staring at it too long.